# product of vector and matrix is a linear combination of row vectors from A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, proof-explanation, matrix-equations

> Theorem:
>
> Let Y be an $n \times$ 1 column vector and A be an $n \times K$ matrix.
> If $Y^{T}$ is a row vector then $Y^{T}A$ is a linear combination of  rows of A with coefficient from $Y^{T}$

Proof:

$\left(Y^{T}A \right )_{ik}$

= $\sum_{j=1}^{n}y_{ij}A_{jk}$

but only one row exists for $Y^{T}$ so for sake of convenience, drop the row index

= $\sum_{j=1}^{m}y_{j}A_{jk}$

= $y_{1}A_{1k} + y_{2}A_{2k} + y_{3}A_{3k} + \cdot \cdot \cdot+y_{n}A_{nK} \in \mathbb{R}$

From here we observe that for a row vector of dimension $1 \times n$ and coefficient matrix A of dimension $n \times K$

$\left [ y_{1} \cdot \cdot \cdot y_{n} \right ] \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} &a_{12}  &a_{13}  &\cdot  &\cdot  &\cdot &a_{1K}\\ 
 a_{21}&a_{22}  &a_{23}  &\cdot  &\cdot  &\cdot &a_{2K} \\ 
 \cdot&  &  &  &  & &\\ 
 \cdot&  &  &  &  & &\\ 
 \cdot&  &  &  &  & &\\ 
 a_{n1}&a_{n2}  &a_{n3}  &\cdot  &\cdot  &\cdot & a_{nK}\\
\end{bmatrix}$

which gives

$y_{1}a_{11}+y_{2}a_{21}+ \cdot \cdot \cdot + y_{n}a_{n1}$

$y_{1}a_{12}+y_{2}a_{22}+ \cdot \cdot \cdot + y_{n}a_{n2}$

$\cdot$

$\cdot$

$\cdot$

$y_{1}a_{1n}+y_{2}a_{2n}+ \cdot \cdot \cdot +y_{n}a_{nK}$

Clearly, it can be seen $Y^{T}A$ is a linear combination of columns from A rather than rows from A as is required.

Any explanation for this is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clearly $Y^TA$ is a row vector, which equals $y_1$ times the first row of $A$, plus $y_2$ times the second row of $A$ plus and so on like you just proved. Every ENTRY in $Y^TA$ is a linear combination of entries in one column of $A$.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thank you. I can help but still feel uneasy making this claim though. it is evident that each column j of $Y^{T}$ multiplies the j row entries in A but the fact that I can only express the entries of A in the system of linear equation as a column vectors makes it hard to establish that they are row vectors. If you can do some explaining in an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: But what are those “column vectors” in the system of equations you’ve developed? They are $(a_{11}, a_{12}, \dots , a_{n1})^T$, &c, namely, they’re the columns of $A^T$, which are the _rows_ of $A$.